# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to install a software, this error coming  again and again i have tried some solutions which have suggest for similar errors but not working for me. command is given bellow:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \\"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\\""
```

please help

error:

```
 bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: What statement are you running? Is this something inside the file you can find?

Comment: `"R -e \\"install.packages` is a space missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how you escape the quotes. The argument is:

```
"R -e \\"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\\""
```

This can be split into:

- `"R -e \\"`
- `install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`
- `\\""`

The `(` after `packages` is wrong shell syntax.

Do this:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```